# Any way to "debug" react native archive

Tags: react-native

I'va a react native app in development, it work without any problems on ios and android in debug, but when i try to make a signed apk or a archive with the jsbundle direclty in the app instead of the dev server, the app is stuck on my first screen (custom loading screen). it work fine in debug with the jsbundle directly in the app.

I'm using react-native 0.24.1. tried to upgrade to 0.28 and it still stuck.

in short

- DEBUG : code in react server console => Work fine
- DEBUG : jsbundle in the app => Work fine
- RELEASE : code in react server console => Work fine
- RELEASE : jsbundle in the app => stuck on first screen (no crash)

If anyone has a idee how i can debug this.

Comment: Have you tried Android Monitor logs ? https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html ?

Comment: They is nothing in the log that help me. if i compare logs from the dev and the release version, it just seem to freeze at some point.

Comment: How about building a signed apk with dev true ?

Comment: Found the issue, it was related to the minify. on one of the js file i had some code only for prod, and the was a issue with it. fixed it and now it's fine.